# Mapping API Key and external account Id in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to use the AWS API Gateway to Authorize using API Key.

However, my need is that every time some client use the API key to make request using x-api-key header, I want to  see that it is for which account Id in my system.

For example: My system having userID-1 and I have created API key in API Gateway that is APIKey-1 now I want to map it in API Gateway. So,every time request comes to the downstream service I can see the API key as well as account ID.

So, from request  I can identified that APIKey-1 is mapped to UserId-1 and so on.

Appreciate your help.

If any alternative, please let us know.

Thanks,
Keyur

Answer (score 0):

1. ApiKeys is not recommended way to authorizer users. You should try using one of API gateway supported authorization solutions.
2. Why can't you push this mapping ( apikey to user ) to your backend ?

Comment: You are right, so do you have idea what AWS API gateway supports like IdentityServer4 or any other? Once I can identity the user uniquely then I can push mapping  to backed. Thanks @Vishal

Comment: Never used IdentityServer4, but quick google says it impements OpenId Connect. AWS Apigateway supports AWS cognito as authentication mechanism which can integrate with any OpenId connect provider.

Comment: I used IdentityServer4 wih Ocelot and Kong API Gateway. However, I was not sure that can be done with AWS API Gateway. But good to know that it can be achieved with AWS Cognito.